# Why a simple linear git log doesn't seem to be time ordered?

Tags: git, git-log

I have a very simple (no branches, one developer) linear commit history.
However git shows the log out of (time) order (screenshot 1).

I have run also git log --pretty=fulle  (as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177852/why-the-data-of-commits-in-git-log-is-out-of-order)) and the author's dates and commit's dates always coincide, but still the log is out of order (screenshot 2).

More importantly, if I need to hunt for a bug.. which is the effective order I should look for ?? The one given me by the log or the one I will compose myself looking at the date ?

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]

Thanks,
  Antonello

Comment: What's wrong? The older commit is from 2012, the newer one from 2013.

Comment: kill me man... thank you and sorry for having take your time... someone with enough rights can close this question..

Answer (score 0):

such situation can be reached with `git rebase` or `git pull --rebase` commands.

let say developerA and developerB both has copies of 1 repo, developerA commits something at 01.01.2013 (without pushing). Then developerB commits and pushes something at 02.01.2013. Then developerA makes  `git pull --rebase` and `git push`. here you are : history is in 1 line , date order is changed

Comment: Thank you. On the linked question one of the answer claims that "If a commit is rebased or cherry-picked it will be given a new commit date but the original author date will be preserved.", but here I have always commit's date = author's date, doesn't it mean there is no rebase involved ?